# visual studio c# change button tool tip on click

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, click, tooltip

Using C# and Visual Studio 2010, how can I change a button' s tool tip, when it is clicked?

I' m thinking of something like this below, but there isn' t any similar command.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
button.toolTip = "...";
        }
```

Edit

I found this command that works pretty well:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.button, "....");
}
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip btnToolTip = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
btnToolTip.SetToolTip(this.button, "your tip");
```

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what you would do. Just capitalize the 'T' in ToolTip.
Maybe add some kind of counter system to determine whether to change it to that tool tip or to the previous one on click if you're going to have it switching back and forth each time.

Comment: This would cause: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' does not contain a definition for 'ToolTip' and no extension method 'ToolTip' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(button1.ToolTip.Equals("abc"))
       button1.ToolTip = "efg";
  else
       button1.ToolTip = "abc";
}
```

This will allow you to switch back and forth on every click.

Comment: For some reason, the command button1.ToolTip = "efg"; isn' t recognised. 
I found a solution, so it's ok thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

1. Set a tool tip in designer, then in the button click event do this

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
       t.SetToolTip(button1, "test");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

'ToolTip1.SetToolTip multiple use

Private Sub ToolStripStatusLabel1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripStatusLabel1.MouseHover

```
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(StatusStrip1, ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text &
                        Environment.NewLine & "TCP/IP - " & TcpIpAdr &
                        Environment.NewLine & "Domain - " & DomName &
                        Environment.NewLine & "Host - " & HstName)

End Sub
```